# Is it possible to use multi_index on property of a struct in a struct?

Tags: smart-contract, development

can i use the id of a struct in an other struct as return value for multi_index?
like:

```
//@abi table test i64
struct st_test{
    uint64_t id;
    string name;
    uint64_t primary_key() const {return id;}
    /*
    ...
    */
    }

//@abi table main i64
struct st_main {
    uint64_t id;
    st_test other_struct;

    uint64_t primary_key() const {return id;}
    uint64_t by_other_struct() const{return other_struct.id;}
    /*
    ...
    */
    }

    /*
    ...
    */
```

Comment: So, why not just store the id of the another struct but store the whole struct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, the devil is in the details though.

You have to make sure that you correctly serialize both structs, and that you set up the secondary index for the 2nd struct ID correctly in the `multi_index` table.

However, doing it this way will use up a lot of space in your table as you would have the full `other_struct` within your `st_main` struct. It might be better to have two separate tables, and have one table reference the ID in the other somehow. This obviously depends somewhat on your use case though.